Height of texts in each column per page
I am using springer nature latex template sn-jnl, Version 2.1 April 2023. When I use the iicol document class option, the height of text contents of the columns in each page varies. Are there any ways to solve the problem?
\documentclass[sn-mathphys,Numbered,iicol]{sn-jnl}% Default with double column layout

%%%% Standard Packages %%

\usepackage{graphicx}% 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{multirow}% 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}% 
\usepackage{amsthm}% 
\usepackage{mathrsfs}% 
\usepackage[title]{appendix}% 
\usepackage{xcolor}% 
\usepackage{textcomp}% 
\usepackage{manyfoot}% 
\usepackage{booktabs}% 
\usepackage{algorithm}% 
\usepackage{algorithmicx}% 
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% 
\usepackage{listings}% 
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{pgf-pie} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\jyear{2021}%

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}                 
        
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}                   
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}                    
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\raggedbottom 

\begin{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.


... the height of [the] text contents of the columns in each page varies. Are there any ways to solve the problem?

I suggest you replace \raggedbottom -- currently the last instruction in the preamble -- with \flushbottom.
